# electric current in parallel circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

If I have a parallel circuit with two resistors ($R_1=48 \Omega$ and $R_2=16 \Omega$) - and $R_1$ has a $0.1 A$ current running through, is it possible to calculate the current through $R_2$ without having the voltage given, an if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the resistors are in parallel, we have

$$I_1 R_1 = I_2 R_2$$

thus

$$I_2 = I_1 \frac{R_1}{R_2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the voltage on $R_1$, voltage on $R_2$ should be the same, since $R_1$ and $R_2$ are parallel. Then You can calculate current through $R_2$.

Answer (score 0):

1. By [Ohm's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), knowing the current running through a resistor is the same as knowing  the potential difference across the across the resistor $V_1=IR_1$.
2. Connecting two components in [parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Parallel_circuits) cause the two components to be in the same potential difference $V_1=V_2$
3. Thus, $$I_2 = \frac{R_1}{R_2} I_1 =0.3A$$